# Why is a partitioned biblatex bibliography incomplete?

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex and want to split the bibliography into several pieces using keywords. Two of the three pieces printed as expected,and the cites print as normal, but the third piece of the bibliography, using type= and notkey=, does not print.

I've reproduced the problem in a smaller document:

```
\documentclass[b4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,%
    backref=true,%
    indexing=true,%
    sorting=anyt,%,
    style=alphabetic%
    ]%
    {biblatex}
\addbibresource{ARB.bib}
\addbibresource{FAQ.bib}
\addbibresource{IETF.bib}
\addbibresource{ISO.bib}
\addbibresource{Unicode.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\usepackage{url}

\makeindex[intoc]

\title{Test of biblatex
    \author{Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz}
    }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Test text citing bib}

This~\cite{ANSI:J18} is a reference to an ANSI standard. This \cite{ISO:10646} isva reference to an ISO standard.

This~\cite{Unicode} is a reference to the entire standard, this~\cite{USTD:3.9} is a reference to section 3.9 and this~\cite{UAX42} is
a reference to Annex 42. 

This~\cite{RFC:3629} is a reference to an RFC.

This\footcite{UAX44} is a footnote reference to Annex 44.

This~\cite{UFAQs} is a reference to the Unicode FAQs and this~\cite{UFAQ:Chars} is a reference to a specific FAQ.

This~\cite{ARB:RXU} is a reference to RXU

\section{Bibliography}

\printbibliography[%
    keyword=ARB,%
    title={GitHub ARB documents}%
    ]
\printbibliography[%
    keyword=FAQ,%
    title=FAQs%
    ]
\printbibliography[%
    type=standard,%
    notkeyword=FAQ,%
    title={Official documents}%
    ]

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The relevant .bib {retested with type=standard) entries are:

```
@report{ANSI:J18,
    label          = {INCITS 274-1996[S2008]},
    type           = {standard},
    shorthand      = {INCITS 274-1996[S2008]},
    title          = {American National Standard for Information Systems - Programming Language REXX},
    shorttitle     = {ANSI Rexx},
    indexsorttitle = {Rexx ANSI standard},
    keywords       = {ANSI,standard},
    instituition   = {American National Standards Institute (ANSI)},
    url            = {https://webstore.ansi.org/standards/incits/incits2741996s2008},
    urldate        = {2023-09-27}
}
@report{ISO:10646,
    label         = {ISO/IEC 10646},
    type          = {standard},
    title         = {Information technology - Universal coded character set (UCS)},
    indextitle    = {ISO 10646: Information technology - Universal coded character set (UCS)},
    keywords      = {IETF,standard},
    instituition  = {International Standards Organization )ISO)},
    url           = {https://www.iso.org/standard/76835.html},
    urldate       = {2023-09-27}
}
```

Comment: Your entries are of type `report` rather than `standard` so they are filtered out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not provided a working example because most of the required `.bib` files (and entries) are unavailable, but if you say

```
\printbibliography
[...
  type=standard,
]
```

Biblatex will only include entries of `type` standard. Typically, these would be `@standard{...}` entries in your `.bib` files. Neither of the entries you show matches this criterion since neither is `@standard{...}`. Rather, they are both `@report{...}` and would instead match `type=report`.

Note, however, that the standard style map `@standard` to `@misc`, so simply changing the type of your entries may not be a good solution. Depending on other factors, using `keyword` rather than `type` or filtering on `report` rather than `standard` might work better.

Comment: I thought that I had provided the entries for which there was a \cite. IAK, is there a way to select only those entries that have type=standard, or should I throw in another keyword and use that?

Comment: @shmuel Your example cites far more than the 2 entries you provide unless I've missed something. You're also loading a lot of `.bib` files I don't have :).

Comment: @shmuel You **are** selecting only those entries for which `type` is `standard`. But you have not defined any entries whose `type` is `standard`. (Or, if you have, you haven't shown them.) You've only defined entries with `type` `report`. I've edited above to try to make this more explicit/clearer. What makes you think the entries you've defined would match `type=standard`?

Comment: Sorry, I had not updated all of the files. I've added type={standard} to those entries and it still fails, which leaves the question of whether there is a way to filter on the value of the type keyword. If not I'll add standard to the keyword=. The two entries I provide are representative of the failures; any fix that works for them should work for the others.

Comment: @shmuel `type` is the type of entry. You can't make an entry of the `@report` type into the `@standard` type by adding `type=standard`. You have to change the entry type to `@standard`. But that will likely change the formatting in ways you don't want because `@report` is more richly featured than `@standard`. (In the standard styles, `@standard` is just `@misc`.)

Comment: @shmuel Suppose you had an entry for a book and realised it was really an article. You wouldn't add `type=article` into the entry. You'd change `@book` to `@article`. This is just the same but with `@report` and `@standard`.

Comment: That doesn't address the question of whether there is a way to select only those report entries that have a type=standard keyword.

Comment: @shmuel As far as I can tell, `type` is being used for entirely different kinds of things in the two cases. When used as a filter in `\printbibliography`, it refers to the type of entry ((`@`)`article` or (`@`)`book` or whatever); when used in an entry in the `.bib` file, it provides information for formatting the entry. But I'm not sure there's any built-in way to use that for filtering and, if there is, it's not the `type=` option to `\printbibliography`. What you might be able to do is map entries with `type=standard` so they're assigned to a category or get a keyword for filtering.

Comment: I understood what it was doing as soon as you pointed out that type= filters on entry type. However, the documentation of type= in the bibliography states "The type of a manual, patent, report, or thesis.", so wanting to filter on it is perfectly natural, and I have been asking whether there is a way to do that. In the meantime, the hack of using and filtering on a keyword of standard works, and I've opened enhancement issue #1307 in GitHub.

Comment: @shmuel I agree the terminology is confusing. At the very least, the manual should be modified to distinguish the different cases.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hack of filtering on keyword=standard works. Meanwhile, I opened issue #1307 https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1307 asking for an enhancement to allow filtering on both entry type and type. The working hack is:

```
\documentclass[b4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,%
    backref=true,%
    indexing=true,%
    sorting=anyt,%,
    style=alphabetic%
    ]%
    {biblatex}
\addbibresource{ARB.bib}
\addbibresource{FAQ.bib}
\addbibresource{IETF.bib}
\addbibresource{ISO.bib}
\addbibresource{Unicode.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\usepackage{url}

\makeindex[intoc]

\title{Test of biblatex
    \author{Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz}
    }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Test text citing bib}

This~\cite{ANSI:J18} is a reference to an ANSI standard. This \cite{ISO:10646} isva reference to an ISO standard.

This~\cite{Unicode} is a reference to the entire standard, this~\cite{USTD:3.9} is a reference to section 3.9 and this~\cite{UAX42} is
a reference to Annex 42. 

This~\cite{RFC:3629} is a reference to an RFC.

This\footcite{UAX44} is a footnote reference to Annex 44.

This~\cite{UFAQs} is a reference to the Unicode FAQs and this~\cite{UFAQ:Chars} is a reference to a specific FAQ.

This~\cite{ARB:RXU} is a reference to RXU

\section{Bibliography}

\printbibliography[%
    keyword=ARB,%
    title={GitHub ARB documents}%
    ]
\printbibliography[%
    keyword={FAQ},%
    title=FAQs%
    ]
\printbibliography[%
    keyword={standard},%
    notkeyword={FAQ},%
    title={Official documents}%
    ]

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could add the link. 'issue #1307 somewhere on the internet' is a bit vague ;).

Comment: The package information points to the proper GitHub page, but I updated my answer to include the issue URL  <https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1307>. Note that #1307 does not address the documentation.